# Does a Collection which is Thread Safe have to be Synchronized?

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety, hashmap, synchronized

I wanted to use `Collection` for only single threaded environment and I am using a `HashMap` that is synchronized.

However, I still doubt if it is thread safe to have it synchronized or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only using a single thread, you don't *need* a thread-safe collection - `HashMap` should be fine.

You should be very careful to work out your requirements:

- If you're really using a single thread, stick with `HashMap` (or consider `LinkedHashMap`)
- If you're sharing the map, you need to work out what kind of safety you want:

  - If the map is fully populated before it's used by multiple threads, which just read, then
    `HashMap` is still fine.
  - `Collections.synchronizedMap` will only synchronize each individual operation; it still isn't
    safe to iterate in one thread and modify the map in another thread without synchronization.
  - `ConcurrentHashMap` is a more "thoroughly" thread-safe approach, and one I'd generally prefer
    over `synchronizedMap`. It allows for modification during iteration, but doesn't guarantee
    where such modifications will be seen while iterating. Also note that while `HashMap` allows null
    keys and values, `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

For your needs, use `ConcurrentHashMap`. It allows concurrent modification of the Map from several threads without the need to block them. `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` creates a blocking Map which will degrade performance, albeit ensure consistency

Answer (score 3):

1. the standard java HashMap is not synchronized.
2. If you are in a single threaded environment you don't need to worry about synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used `Collection` classes, such as `java.util.ArrayList`, are not synchronized. However, if there's a chance that two threads could be altering a collection concurrently, you can generate a synchronized collection from it using the `synchronizedCollection()` method. Similar to the read-only methods, the thread-safe APIs let you generate a synchronized collection, list, set, or map. For instance, this is how you can generate a synchronized map from a `HashMap`:

```
  Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
  map.put(...
```

Answer (score 0):

As its a single-threaded environment you can safely use HashMap.